# How to use built in iOS camera without using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to create my own picture taking UI in my app. Is this possible? I've seen lots of apps use this feature (other camera apps) who have a custom UI and after you take a picture it doesn't ask if you want to retake the photo. Also it would be nice if it didn't flip the photos taken with the front camera. So how would I do this??

Thanks

Comment: Means u dont want any other SDKS like AVCAM. is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

try this code [GLCamerRipple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011222)

and this as well [SquareCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190)

basically you need to create a class that implements the [AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and start the session with the camera.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a great option: https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision

Alternatively if you want more control you can use AVFoundation as Janub mentioned